# cleaning contents inside of html tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to write a preg_replace that will clean all tag properties of the allowed tags, and all tags that do not exist in the allowed list.

Basic example- this:

```
<p style="some styling here">Test<div class="button">Button Text</div></p>
```

would turn out to be:

```
<p>test</p>
```

I have this working well.. Except for img tags and a href tags.  I need to not clean the properties of the img and a tags. Possibly others. I was not sure if there was a way to set two allow lists?

1) One list for what tags are allowed to stay after being cleaned
2) One list for the tags that are allowed but left alone?
3) The rest are deleted.

Here is the script I am working on:

```
$string = '<p style="width: 250px;">This is some text<div class="button">This is the button</div><br><img src="waves.jpg" width="150" height="200" /></p><p><b>Title</b><br>Here is some more text and <a href="#" target="_blank">this is a link</a></p>';

$output = strip_tags($string, '<p><b><br><img><a>');
$output = preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i", '<$1$2$3$4$5>', $output);

echo $output;
```

This script should clean the $string to be:

```
<p>This is some text<br><img src="waves.jpg" width="150" height="200" /></p><p><b>Title</b><br>Here is some more text and <a href="#" target="_blank">this is a link</a></p>
```

Comment: Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you į̷̷͚̤̤̖̱̦͍͗̒̈̅̄̎n̨͖͓̹͍͎͔͈̝̲͐ͪ͛̃̄͛ṣ̷̵̞̦ͤ̅̉̋ͪ͑͛ͥ͜a̷̘͖̮͔͎͛̇̏̒͆̆͘n͇͔̤̼͙̩͖̭ͤ͋̉͌͟eͥ͒͆ͧͨ̽͞҉̹͍̳̻͢](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: Any suggestions as to which and possibly some simple code example? I referenced the links you placed but there is so much information and so many options I am just lost... It seems those parsers are to get information between the tags of items.  I am not trying to do that (unless I am not understanding)..  I am trying to clean the properties in the opening tag.

Comment: Looks like you're parseing XHTML.  Why not just Simple XML? http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/aoOOUN

This function will strip an element of disallowed sub elements, clean its "stripped" sub elements, and leave the rest (recursively).

```
function clean($element, $allowed, $stripped){
    if(!is_array($allowed) || ! is_array($stripped)) return;
    if(!$element)return;
    $toDelete = array();
    foreach($element->childNodes as $child){
        if(!isset($child->tagName))continue;
        $n = $child->tagName;
        if ($n && !in_array($n, $allowed) && !in_array($n, $stripped)){
            $toDelete[] = $child;
            continue;
        }
        if($n && in_array($n, $stripped)){
            $attr = array();
            foreach($child->attributes as $a)
                $attr[] = $a->nodeName;
            foreach($attr as $a)
                $child->removeAttribute($a);
        }
        clean($child, $allowed, $stripped);
    }
    foreach ($toDelete as $del)
        $element->removeChild($del);
}
```

This is the code to clean your string:

```
$xhtml = '<p style="width: 250px;">This is some text<div class="button">This is the button</div><br><img src="waves.jpg" width="150" height="200" /></p><p><b>Title</b><br>Here is some more text and <a href="#" target="_blank">this is a link</a></p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($xhtml);
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
clean($body, array('img', 'a'), array('p', 'br', 'b'));
echo preg_replace('#^.*?<body>(.*?)</body>.*$#s', '$1', $dom->saveHTML($body));
```

You should check out the Documentation for [PHP's DOM classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: I was excited when I saw this, but it puts weird characters in the output. Like : Â  Â  (not sure if those will pass though)

Comment: Those are probably due to UTF-8 encoding.  Can you provide example input and output with the "weird" characters?

Comment: The data is sensitive, is there a way to transfer without posting via here publicly? Can we send via email?

Comment: John, if you can't post it here, you shouldn't email it to me.  See if you can create a use case with example, non-sensitive data to show how it corrupted your data.  Check to see if there are non-ascii characters in your string (things like the "Pound Sterling" currency symbol, letters with diacritical marks), or sometimes even the single and double quote characters - especially if you're copying in from a Microsoft product.)

Comment: I will create a example using dummy text, will take a bit.  Thanks! :)